# ms access query pivot

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.

```
tblA
ID   Date      Price
--------------------
1    10/1/18   100
2    10/2/18   200
3    10/1/19    50

tblB
ID   Date      Price
------------------
1    10/5/18   100
2    10/6/18   100
3    10/7/18   100
```

I have the following query to sum price per month.

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS PricePerMonth
SELECT Format([AllDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], t.Name
FROM (
    SELECT [Date] as AllDate, Nz(Price, 0) AS SumPrice, 'tblA' As Name
    FROM tblA
UNION All
    SELECT [Date] as AllDate, Nz(Price, 0) AS SumPrice, 'tblB' As Name
    FROM tblB
)  AS t
GROUP BY Format([AllDate],"yyyy"), t.Name
ORDER BY Format([AllDate],"yyyy") DESC , t.Name
PIVOT Month([AllDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Output Query:

```
Year  Name     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019  tblA    50    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2018  tblA   100  200    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2018  tblB     0    0    0    0  100  100  100    0    0     0     0     0
```

Is there a way to have this output:

```
Year  Name     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019  tblA    50    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2019  tblB     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0   <===Different from above.
2018  tblA   100  200    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2018  tblB     0    0    0    0  100  100  100    0    0     0     0     0
```

As you can see, tblB has no data on year 2019. So I need to find a way to add it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS PricePerMonth
SELECT Format([AllDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], t.Name
FROM (
   SELECT [Date] as AllDate, Nz(Price, 0) AS SumPrice, 'tblA' As Name
   FROM tblA
UNION All
   SELECT [Date] as AllDate, Nz(Price, 0) AS SumPrice, 'tblB' As Name
   FROM tblB
UNION ALL
   SELECT [Date] as AllDate, 0 AS SumPrice, 'tblA' As Name
   FROM tblB
UNION ALL
   SELECT [Date] as AllDate, 0 AS SumPrice, 'tblB' As Name
   FROM tblA
)  AS t
GROUP BY  t.Name,Format([AllDate],"yyyy")
ORDER BY Format([AllDate],"yyyy") DESC , t.Name
PIVOT Month([AllDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

Comment: @MaryEU But the query is not giving correct results.

Comment: @MaryEU  ok great But you should go for query which takes time rather than incorrect results.

Comment: @Santosh Do you think it will be a good idea to create a temp query and add this in the query. Will it speed up more? So there will be 2 query.

Comment: The query should run fine without any speed issues.

Comment: @Santosh Thank you for yor time.

Comment: @YvetteLee Thank you for yor time.

Answer (score 1):

Added additional Select in Union All which gets the dates missing from another table.

```
    TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS PricePerMonth
SELECT Format([AllDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], t.Name
FROM (
       SELECT [Date] as AllDate, Nz(Price, 0) AS SumPrice, 'tblA' As Name
    FROM tblA
UNION All
    SELECT [Date] as AllDate, Nz(Price, 0) AS SumPrice, 'tblB' As Name
    FROM tblB

Union All

SELECT  tblb.Date as dt, 0 ,  'tblA' As Name
FROM tblB Left  JOIN tblA ON  Format(tblA.[Date],'yyyy')  = Format(tblB.[Date],'yyyy') 
where not Format(tblA.Date,'yyyy') = Format(tblb.Date,'yyyy')

Union All

SELECT (tblA.Date) as dt, 0 ,  'tblB' As Name
FROM tblA Left  JOIN tblB ON  Format(tblA.[Date],'yyyy')  = Format(tblB.[Date],'yyyy') 
where not Format(tblA.Date,'yyyy') = Format(tblb.Date,'yyyy')

)  AS t
GROUP BY  t.Name,Format([AllDate],"yyyy")
ORDER BY Format([AllDate],"yyyy") DESC , t.Name
PIVOT Month([AllDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

[image]

Using the @YvetteLee query the results looks like below ( added screenshot just to show the difference)
[image]

Comment: It is taking 5+ minutes to load the query. But it is working.

Comment: Any tweak to make it faster?

Comment: Just try adding distinct after select

Comment: Updated, just check and let me know

Comment: Added. Still too long to load.

Comment: Can you run the select queries individually and see how much times each takes so that you know which query has to be optimized. I believe because of format conversion and this where clause `where not Format(tblA.Date,'yyyy') = Format(tblb.Date,'yyyy')` its taking too much time. Let me know and will see possible options to optimize the query.

Comment: @MaryEU Just check out the screenshot added